# Element Paths for Search Parameters

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to find the most reliable way to determine which element in a resource a given search parameter refers to. So far I process the xpath expression and hope to find a match, but this seems hacky.

Is there a standard or more consistent way to determine what element(s) within a resource a search parameter should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now - parsing the XPath is it.  This is an active point of discussion in the standards group and will probably result in some modification to the SearchParameter resource (I hope!).

Comment: Thanks Chris, path values certainly would make derivation easier. As an HL7 member, Is there a way I can be more involved with the the standards group on this issue?

Comment: Discussion on the FHIR email list, and against a FHIR gForge task that Chris created (gForge is down, so I can't find the task, maybe Chris can post the link)

Comment: GForge tracker #8847 http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=8847&start=0